# A phrase describing anomaly multiplicator

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Let's say the anomaly occurs when the current value is 10 times bigger than 2 previous values. But I want to have the opportunity to change value '10' to something else.

How do I name this '10 times'? I was thinking about 'anomaly multiplicator' or 'anomaly threshold' but they don't sound good.

EDIT

The anomaly is about read pages of a book. So the user is writing the number of pages he/she read every day and the task is to find out when the anomaly occurs.
For example, Anna read 10 pages on Monday, 15 pages on Tuesday and 2 pages on Wednesday. 'Anomaly multiplicator' is 3. The average of 2 last days is (10+15)/2 = 12,5 pages. The anomaly occurs because 12,5 > 2*3. I want to let Anna choose this 'anomaly multiplicator'.

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain some more about whether this "anomaly" is something happening by accident (which is what one would expect from the name) or whether it's under your control, and can you add an example sentence please.

Comment: Please check my edit

Comment: There's still no example sentence.

Comment: I think the primary problem is with the term "anomaly". This is not a common expression in non-technical English, and tends to suggest something weird has happened, rather than something as "normal" as activity dropping below a user-defined threshold as your example describes.

Comment: Have you heard about something called *standard deviation*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more or less implied that it is an anomaly when a *threshold* is breached. So, using *anomaly* itself in the term may be misleading.

You may consider ***variation threshold***.

Except that your threshold will no longer be *n* but a **percentage** value given by:

> Threshold = (n-1)X100%

Like this:

> If you original *n* is 3, you can tolerate a value up to 3 X (previous
> value) or an increase of 200% which will be your variation threshold.
>
> Similarly, where n = 10, the variation
> threshold is 900%.

From **oxforddictionaries.com**:

> [**variation**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/variation)
> *NOUN*
>
> **1A** change or slight difference in condition, amount, or level, typically within certain limits: regional variations in house prices
>
> [MASS NOUN]: the figures showed marked variation from year to year
>
> [**threshold**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/threshold)
> *NOUN*
>
> **2** The magnitude or intensity that must be exceeded for a certain reaction, phenomenon, result, or condition to occur or be manifested:
> nothing happens until the signal passes the threshold [AS MODIFIER]: a
> threshold level

Note: I used 'X' above as the multiplication operator.